# Perl - Save each entry in file at new line

Tags: perl

I am working on a Perl script that checks the contents of a directory using `glob` and then writes the output to a new file. But the each entries in the file are separated using spaces and I need it to print each entry in new line. My code is like this

```
open(New, ">/u/smanik/xyz.txt");

@files = glob('/user/manik/*.csv');
$size  = @files;

print "Total no of files: $size \n";

print New @files;

open(New, "/user/manik/xyz.txt");
while ( <New> ) {
    print "$_";
}

close(New);
```

This is giving output by printing in the file as

```
/user/manik/A.csv /user/manik/B.csv
```

But I need it to be printed in the file like this

```
A.csv
B.csv
C.csv
```

I tried by adding `\n` in the fifth line but that didn't work.

Comment: I don't think there are spaces in between. If that's your complete code, it should be `/user/manik/A.csv/user/manik/B.csv`. Maybe you have `print New "@files"`?

Comment: `\n` is newline, not `/n`

Comment: sorry for misprint actually i used \n only

Comment: Here's a quick code review First, you should always `use strict` and `use warnings` in your code, and declare all your variables lexically using `my`, i.e. `my $size = @files`. You should also use lexical file handles instead of the globals (your `New`, which by convention should have been all uppercase, so `NEW`). You should also use three-arg `open` to avoid security problems if your filename comes from a var and contains metachars at the front. Finally, check for errors: `open my $fh, '>', '/user/manikxyz.txt' or die $!`.

Comment: Thanks @simbabque I will keep that in mind next time

Comment: I have fixed the indentation in your code sample. You're welcome, but please do it yourself next time. Consistent indentation is an important tool for understanding code and if you're asking a group of people to read and understand your code, it's only polite to make it as easy as possible for them

Comment: Thanks Dave for your help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want it to print newlines, you need to tell it that.

```
my @foo = (1, 2, 3);
print @foo;
```

This will print

123

That's because the array `@foo` is taken as the list of arguments to `print`, which will just output all the arguments one after another.

```
my @foo = (1, 2, 3);
print "@foo";
```

Now this will print

```
1 2 3
```

because an array inside a double quoted `""` string is being interpolated using the `$,` [output field separator](https://perldoc.perl.org/perlvar.html#%24%2C), which is a blank space  by default.

If you want it to use newlines, the easiest way is to [`join`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/join.html) your array with `\n`, which produces a single string as the argument for `print`.

```
my @foo = ( 1, 2, 3 );
print join "\n", @foo;
```

That will give you

```
1
2
3
```

Comment: Thanks this is doing the trick. But I also need to remove that /user/manik/ from start of each entry

Comment: @ManikSharma if you have a new question, please ask a new question. But I suggest you try for yourself first.

Comment: I have an irrational hatred of the `print join "\n", @foo` idiom! This is mainly because I think of `\n` as a record *terminator*, and not a record separator. Accordingly I think `print "$_\n" for @foo` (which is the same number of characters) or `say for @foo` is much better, but feel free to ignore me.

Comment: @Borodin I see your point. In fact I was thinking about the `for` solution, but decided not to go with it because I thought it's more complicated.